# Is it possible to add an alternate key to a derived type in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

On the project I'm working on we're pulling some base models from a library that was internally made by us. We use it for several projects and has been very helpful so far. The issue I'm having is that we have a special scenario in which we need to make one of the additional attributes on the derived model an alternate key but EntityFramework is complaining that an AK cant be created on a derived type. Here's a basic example of what I'm trying to accomplish (with alot of fat trimmed):

**Imported Library**

```
namespace InternalLibrary
{
    public class BaseCustomer
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int FirstName { get; set; }
        public int LastName { get; set; }
    }

    public class BaseCustomerMap
    {
        public BaseCustomerMap(EntityTypeBuilder<BaseCustomer> entityBuilder)
        {
            entityBuilder
                .HasKey(t => t.Id );

            entityBuilder.Property(t => t.Id)
                .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
        }
    }
}
```

**Current Project**

```
namespace CurrentProject
{
    public class Customer : InternalLibrary.BaseCustomer
    {
        public string AdditionalStrField { get; set; }
        public int AdditionalIntField { get; set; }
    }

    public class CustomerMap
    {
        public CustomerMap(EntityTypeBuilder<Customer> entityBuilder)
        {
            entityBuilder
                .HasAlternateKey(t => t.AdditionalIntField );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, one thought from my Googling is to make sure you don't have any properties in your model as `object` type. See [here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/3727).

Answer (score 0):

Well, for one, your `CustomerMap` class should inherit from the `BaseCustomerMap` class.

```
public class CustomerMap : BaseCustomerMap
{
    public CustomerMap(EntityTypeBuilder<Customer> entityBuilder)
        : base(entityBuilder)
    {
        entityBuilder
            .HasAlternateKey(t => t.AdditionalIntField );
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Yeah. I answered too quickly and didn't really pay attention that closely. You should make your `BaseCustomerMap` class generic:

```
public class BaseCustomerMap<TEntity>
    where TEntity : BaseCustomer
{
    public BaseCustomerMap(EntityTypeBuilder<TEntity> entityBuilder)
    {
        entityBuilder
            .HasKey(t => t.Id );

        entityBuilder.Property(t => t.Id)
            .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
    }
}
```

Then, you can do:

```
public class CustomerMap : BaseCustomerMap<Customer>
```

Really, you don't want to be configuring the base class, anyways, since that likely shouldn't actually be part of your context. What you're looking for is the ability to share the *configuration* for all entities that derive from `BaseCustomer`, which generics buy you.

Comment: I tried that but unfortunately when I do that it gives me an error: cannot convert from Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders.EntityTypeBuilder<CurrentProject.Customer> to Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders.EntityTypeBuilder<InternalLibrary.BaseCustomer>